# ASP.NET & CS & Visual Studio 2010 - файл не реагирует на изменения

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Есть файл ASPX и соответствующий ему файл ASPX.CS (CodeBehind="Filename.aspx.cs"). Изменения в файле ASPX приводят к видимым изменениям в проекте. Изменения в ASPX.CS не меняют ничего, в т.ч. полное уничтожение кода.
В чём дело?
Проект ОЧЕНЬ стар, на VS 2015 не запускается вообще. Создан в 2014 кем-то, похоже, криворуким. Мы пишем на JS и PHP, языков этих не знаем и VS обычно не пользуем, но разобраться надо. Возможно, есть какое-то очевидное решение, неизвестное новичкам?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

"Изменения в файле ASPX приводят к видимым изменениям в проекте" - не в проекте, а в странице.

"Изменения в ASPX.CS не меняют ничего" - после изменений в коде проект надо перекомпилировать.

Где находится файл *.aspx.cs по отношению к корню проекта?

Если Вы намеренно сделаете синтактическию ошибку в коде *.aspx.cs, Вы получаете ошибку компиляции?

*Философическое:*

Если бы я был в тупиковой ситуации, когда у меня что-то не работает, я не знаю, что делать, и обращаюсь за помощью, я бы вываливал максимум информации с кодом, конфигурацией, полным текстом сообщений об ошибках, в конце концов, картинками из VS. Из Вас же информацию приходится буквально выдавливать по капле.

Comment: Разумеется, он был перекомпилирован. Это также ничего не меняет.

Comment: что в этом проекте считается корнем? Есть wwwroot, в нём - файл .aspx, и если нажать стрелочку рядом с ним, то открывается как бы "вложенный" .aspx.cs

Comment: Ошибки есть даже в нетронутом проекте. Если заставить запуститься несмотря на - запускается. Но любые изменения в *.aspx.cs, даже полное уничтожение всего кода, ничего не меняют.

Comment: @user240458 раз есть ошибки - значит компиляция обрывается, и бинарники остаются старые. правьте ошибки пока не скопмилируется все целиком.

Comment: "wwwrooot" - точно три "о"?

Comment: @ PashaPash♦ мы подозреваем это и пытались. Но, во-первых, ошибки там вроде "не найден такой-то css-свойство", а во-вторых, при попытках править они множатся и множатся. И ещё: файл .aspx всё же меняется. Если допустить ошибку там, это сразу появляется на странице.

Comment: @Igor две, извините.

Comment: закройте закладку редактора с *.aspx маркапом и скомпилируйте. Есть ошибки в cs файле? Какие?

Comment: Весь этот замечательный проект работает, сайт активен, действия выполняются. Но нам надо внести изменения (добавить действие).

Comment: @Igor Есть три ошибки, все три - "не удалось загрузить тип".

Comment: "не удалось загрузить тип" - и все?

Comment: @Igor 3 errors, 7 warnings, 0 messages

Comment: @Igor если нажать на ошибку, вылезает ещё дикое количество ошибок, других. Что это значит?

Comment: Ошибка компиляции должна указывать на конкретную строчку кода. Было бы полезно включить в вопрос этот код (желательно - весь метод, а то и класс) с указанием строки и полного текста ошибки.

Comment: @Igor Error 26 Не удалось загрузить тип 'AdminPanel.AddLocalBusiness'. ...\site\wwwroot\AddLocalBusiness.aspx и ссылается это на CodeBehind="AddLocalBusiness.aspx.cs", что логично. Это первая ошибка. Вторая похожая, только требует другой файл, при нажатии на неё выскакивает 32 других, типа Error 46 The name 'ddl_brands' does not exist in the current context ...\site\wwwroot\Sales.aspx.cs 43 41 C:\...\wwwroot\ 
Их много, меняются только names. Здесь ограниченная длина сообщения, могу скопировать весь блок по частям, но смысл в том, что запрашиваемое упоминается для сравнения с чем-то другим.

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c638224/v638224982/2c019/Pmbz6PMNjvc.jpg